# Photo in like box distorted

Tags: facebook, photo

I have embeded the Facebook Like box iframe on my web site and it's skewing/distorting the photos.  They are elongated.  They look fine on the actual Fb page, it's the embedded photos that are messed up.  It was not a problem until about 2 weeks ago.

Two samples:  www.photographsbyjim.com and www.riflesinc.com

Answer (score 0):

They look perfect to me..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've reverse-engineered the algorithm that Facebook are using, and it's quite complex. I don't know what they're thinking, but they undoubtedly intend for the distortion to happen.

As far as I can tell, only a picture 171 x 320 will not be distorted.

David

Answer (score 0):

It appears to happen differently in different browsers. IE and Firefox display some photos distorted and Safari and Chrome are displaying different ones distorted.

Comment: This does not answer the question.